# Codeigniter return NULL from validation callback

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

I'm using a callback to validate URLs submitted by a text input. I need to insert `NULL` in the database if the text input is empty (meaning the user erased his/her URL entry). I'm trying the code below but it just inserts an empty string in the database.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('image_url', 'Image URL', 'trim|xss_clean|prep_url|callback__validate_url');
```

The callback:

```
    function _validate_url($str)
    {
        if (isset($str))
        {
            $pattern = "/^(http|https):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i";
            if (!preg_match($pattern, $str))
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('_validate_url', 'URL is not valid');
                return FALSE;
            }
            else 
            {
                if (!isset($str)) //if input empty
                {
                    return NULL; //return NULL to input?
                }

                return TRUE;
            }
        }

        return TRUE; 
    }
```

How can I return a value to the input via a callback?

**Update:**

The code above is wrong and I was not able to return `NULL` in the input (I'm guessing because its returns a string) so I did it outside the callback

```
   $image_url = $this->input->post('image_url');

    if (empty($image_url)) 
    { 
         $image_url = NULL; 
    }

    $data = array (
            'content' => $this->input->post('content'),
            'image_url' => $entry_image_url
    );

    //add to database
```

Comment: `if (!isset($str)) //if input empty` -- this condition will never be `true`. `$str` variable is always set

Comment: @zerkms - `isset()` returns false if a variable is set to `null`.

Comment: @zerkms if that's so I would have gotten a validation error every time I left the URL input empty. Notice the first `isset($str)` that one seems to work because the callback returns `TRUE` when `$str` is not set

Comment: @Sam Dufel: oops, right. But it is still not semantic. If the aim is to check if variable is null or not - there is `is_null()` for that

Comment: Right, he probably should be checking `strlen` or `empty` or something more useful.  An automated callback really shouldn't be getting passed null values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this piece of code, it's got an impossible condition:

```
    if (isset($str)) // Everything in this block runs if $str is "set"
    {
        if (!preg_match($pattern, $str))
        {
            //
        }
        else 
        {
            if (!isset($str)) // But you're checking if $str is not set....
            {
                // This can never happen!
            }

        }
    }
```

Replace that condition with an appropriate way to check if the input is empty, perhaps check if  `trim($str) === ''` or even `empty($str)`.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't notice that. Think I need to take a break.. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if you really feel you need NULLs in your DB you should explicitly say so, I don't think it would be safe to rely on the form validation class to properly convert input values to NULL, even though it *might* work (input data like POST and GET are always a string or array of strings). Why can't an empty string suffice?

Comment: Well when creating entries I'm setting the `image_url` column to `NULL` as default and I want to keep that structure if a user removes the url when they update their entry. Also when displaying images on the site I'm using `isset()` to check if images exist, an empty string will show the broken image icon. Lastly, I'm also setting NULL if they upload an image rather than paste an URL and vice versa.

Comment: So I guess you're using `WHERE image_url IS NOT NULL` to grab the images then? My point is that you really shouldn't *need* to differentiate between a NULL and an empty string - but it's your choice of course. I'm sure if we were sitting at the same desk looking at the code I could help make things a bit easier, best of luck with your app.